# Connecting LEGO WeDo USB hub to portable Power Bank

Tags: compatibility, battery, wedo

Is it possible to connect the LEGO usb hub from education WeDo series to a portable power bank for power?

**WeDo USB Hub**

[image]

**Portable Power Bank**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it uses a standard USB charging configuration. These are designed to be universal, making power distribution easier and cheaper.

Comment: While this would power the hub, how would it be controlled then? I was under the impression the hub was controlled from a PC - via the USB connection.